is it necessary using transforms?
I have
old wix setup project.
I converted it to the v4 version using HeatWave
But the project still uses things that I don't know if they need forexample
XSLT - Transformation
What do You think, is it necessary ?
 <HeatDirectory Transforms="$(ProjectDir)\Components.xslt" OutputFile="ComponentsGenerated.wxs"  DirectoryRefId="TARGETDIR" ComponentGroupName="PublishedComponents"  SuppressUniqueIds="false" SuppressCom="true" Directory="..\SposOnboard.Application\bin\$(Configuration)\"  SuppressFragments="true" SuppressRootDirectory="true" AutogenerateGuids="false"  GenerateGuidsNow="true" PreprocessorVariable="var.BasePath" SuppressRegistry="true" />
My transform file looks like that:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:wix="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
                xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
                exclude-result-prefixes="wix">

  <!--Load all components-->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Filter components-->
  <xsl:key name="pdb-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.pdb')]" use="@Id" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('pdb-search', @Id)]" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('pdb-search', @Id)]" />

  <!--Override SAMPLE.exe component-->
  <xsl:key name="sampleExe-search" match="wix:Component[wix:File/@Source='$(var.BasePath)\SAMPLE.exe']" use="@Id" />  
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('sampleExe-search', @Id)]" >
    <Component Id="cmpSample" Guid="{@Guid}">
      <File Id="filSample" Source="$(var.BasePath)\SAMPLE.exe"/>
      <ProgId Id="SAMPLE Weather file" Description="Weather information used to route ships over the oceans" Icon="Sample.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes">
        <Extension Id="sps" Advertise="yes">
          <MIME ContentType="application/sps" Default="yes" />
          <Verb Id="open" Command="&amp;Open" Argument="&quot;%1&quot;" Sequence="1" />
        </Extension>
      </ProgId> 
    </Component>
    <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" Guid="60F4A4B3-DD4D-4FD6-B6AE-9C5EB8FCC0D1" Directory="DesktopFolder" Condition="CREATE_DESKTOP_ICON">
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\TechGroup\SAMPLE_9" Name="DesktopShortcutEnabled" Value="1"></RegistryValue>
      <Shortcut Name="SAMPLE_9" Directory="DesktopFolder" Target="[#filSample]" Icon="Sample.exe"></Shortcut>
    </Component>
    <Component Id="MenuShortcut" Guid="771174C2-CAC8-4E32-9BC6-C91D5458C9FA" Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Condition="CREATE_MENU_ITEMS">
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\TechGroup\SAMPLE_9" Name="MenuShortcutEnabled" Value="1"></RegistryValue>
      <Shortcut Name="SAMPLE_9" Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Target="[#filSample]" Icon="Sample.exe"></Shortcut>
    </Component>
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('sampleExe-search', @Id)]" >
    <ComponentRef Id="cmpSample" />
    <ComponentRef Id="DesktopShortcut" />
    <ComponentRef Id="MenuShortcut" />
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!--Override SAMPLE.exe.cofig component-->
  <xsl:key name="sampleExeConfig-search" match="wix:Component[wix:File/@Source='$(var.BasePath)\SAMPLE.exe.config']" use="@Id" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('sampleExeConfig-search', @Id)]" >
    <Component Id="cmpSampleConfig" Guid="{@Guid}">
      <File Id="filSampleConfig" Source="$(var.BasePath)\SAMPLE.exe.config" />
    </Component>     
  </xsl:template>    
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('sampleExeConfig-search', @Id)]" >
    <ComponentRef Id="cmpSampleConfig" />  
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


The transforms are still necessary, as the upgrade to v4 did not change or obsolete their functionality.
Transforms are super useful for modifying the heat harvest output without touching the directory structure itself. Anything they did in v3 will still be needed in v4.
If you want to remove it and keep the same end result, you will likely need to modify the folders/files in SposOnboard.Application\bin$(Configuration) to have what you need with no transformation. You can get more specific advice on what that could look like if you show us the transform file.

I have attached the transformation file please see ?

It looks like it is still definitely needed. That transform will prevent any .pdb files in the output directory from being harvested, which is usually what you want. It will also add a bunch of functionality to the Sample.exe program, including a desktop/menu shortcut and some other things. So you still need it unless you want to find other ways of handling what it currently does for you.
